# Fix Bootstrap button CSS style

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have two social media buttons (one Anchor Tag, One Button Tag, using different tags for experimental purpose only).

The issue is that when I click on the button, its color and  border changes to default bootstrap .btn styling (black color, blue border. While I want #33CAFF color and #33CAFF border).

Please note that the color changes back to #33CAFF once I click elsewhere on the screen.

But I want that after clicking the button, the styling should set to its pre click state.

Images for clarity:

What's happening right now

[image]

What I want

[image]

Comment: LInk to the code: https://jsfiddle.net/bhm1a1dh/29/

Comment: why you are using link for FB and button for twitter?

Comment: @JeetDaloneboy Just playing around with different tags.

Comment: A lot of people are puzzled as to why have I used one anchor and one button tag.
I am experimenting with different tags, that's the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the below code.

```
.myBtn:focus {
    background-color:#fff;
  color:#33CAFF;
  outline:none;
}
```

here is the [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhm1a1dh/31/).

Comment: I tried it earlier, the only difference I noted is that you have defined .myBtn:focus before .myBtn:hover. Must be some issue with precedence of pseudo selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Please put your desired color code in css like this

```
.btn or button class / Id name: focus{
color:#33CAFF; (your color code)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `<a>` for facebook and `<button>` for twitter

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito);
body{
  background-color:#33CAFF;
  font-family:'Nunito',sans-serif;
}
#myDiv{
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#33CAFF;
  margin-top:20px;
  padding:20px;
  line-spacing:1.5px;
}
.myBtn{
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#33CAFF;
  border:1px solid #33CAFF;
  border-radius:0;
  padding:10px;
  margin:5px;
}
a:visited{
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#33CAFF;
}
.myBtn:hover{
  background-color:#33CAFF;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a:active{
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#33CAFF;
}
button:focus{
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="myDiv" class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 text-center">
      <h2>Some Text to go here</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te eam option discere saperet, quo porro libris te, quo ea eirmod gloriatur. Qui et mutat numquam consetetur, mei blandit delectus no, eam at adipisci senserit. Cibo error at mei. At pri nullam altera, pri diam noster scripta eu. Eu quot iudicabit sadipscing vix.       </p>
      <a type="button" class="btn myBtn">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook
      </a>
      <a type="button" class="btn myBtn">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhm1a1dh/30/) link

Comment: I am experimenting with tags. It would be great if you can help me in fixing the button styling.

Answer (score 0):

The following css change will do:

```
.myBtn:focus
    {
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#33CAFF;
    border:1px solid #33CAFF;
    }
```

But still i don't see the need to have one as a button and the other as a link.

Comment: Experimenting with different tags, would use the most appropriate one in actual projects.